# Trying to resize a UIViewRepresentable of a UIImage in swiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I've got my with the `resize` method:

```
//
//  ImageView.swift
//  fairytales
//
//  Created by Justin Zaun on 7/12/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 JGZ. All rights reserved.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ImageView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    var name: String
    
    fileprivate var imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()
    fileprivate var originalImage: UIImage
    

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.originalImage = UIImage(named: name)!
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIImageView {
        imageView.image = self.originalImage

        return imageView;
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIImageView, context: Context) {
    }
    
    fileprivate func scaledImage(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        let size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        if (self.originalImage.size == size) {
            return self.originalImage
        }
        
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
        self.originalImage.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        
        return image!;
    }
    
    func resize(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) -> some View {
        self.imageView.image = scaledImage(width: width, height: height)
        print(self.imageView.image!.size)

        return self.frame(width: width, height: height)
    }
}
```

Inside a view I try...

```
ImageView(name: "Letter-T")
    .resize(width: 100, height: 100)
```

The print statement, prints the correct size, but onscreen the image is not resized. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4 as well.

Comment: @Asperi - Xcode 11.5 / iOS 13.5. I'm making this the only view in the app and it still won't resize.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out @Justin808?

Answer (score 0):

in UIViewRepresentable you should use bindings as swiftui redraws view with binding value changes (in updateUIView)
also swiftui provides container for uikit view in UIViewRepresentable, it doesn't mean that returned uikit view in makeUIView will make its size equal to loaded image size
tip:

```
struct SUIRemoteImage: View {
    @State private(set) var uiImage: UIImage?
    @Binding var url: String

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if let image = uiImage {
                Image(uiImage: image)
                    .resizable()
            } else {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            loadImage()
        }
        .onChange(of: url) { _ in
            loadImage()
        }
    }
    
    private func loadImage() {
        //get img and attach data to uiImage (in main thread)
    }
}
```